# How can I resolve the 'unable to find executable' error when trying to run Swift code in VSCode on MacOS?

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code

When I try to run my swift code in VSCode, (I am on macos); it says

`"unable to find executable for /Users/User1/Documents/MyPlayground.playground/<executable file>'"`

what does this mean and I how can I get my code to run.

I tried running,

```swift
var name: String = "Bob"
print("Hello \(name)!")
```

but it came up with the error
this is my launch.json (not sure if this helps but it told me to open it when the error popped up)

```json
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/<executable file>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Any reason you can’t use Xcode since you are using a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by adding the name of the executable file to `launch.json`. Here's how I did it:

1. Pull up the terminal in VSCode, and enter the command `swiftc <filename>.swift` (what this does is compile the file, and create an executable file)
2. After the command finishes execution, enter `./<filename>` (without the .swift file extension)
3. Your code should run— but we want the error to go away. So close and save the project, and restart VSCode.
4. Open your project again, and this time, you should see an extra file in the Explorer (the name of the file should be the same as the file you wanted to run). This is the executable file.
5. Open `launch.json`, and go to the line that says `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/<executable file>"`
6. Replace `<executable file>` with the name of the executable file (don't worry about the file extension).
7. Save and close `launch.json`, and run your project. It should work now!

Edit: Using this method, you have to re-compile the program with `swiftc <filename>.swift` each time you want to run it again.

I hope this helps!